# JS event Loop confuse

Tags: javascript, v8, event-loop

I am pretty new to JS event loop, I wonder if anyone could give me a brief walk thru about how js engine run this:

```
function start(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Timeout")
  }, 0)
  setImmediate(function(){
    console.log("Immediate")
  })
  process.nextTick(function(){
    console.log("next tick")
  })
}
```

The result is :

```
next tick
Timeout
Immediate
```

I thought when JS engine runs this,

1. it parses the script, set Timer, set Immediate, set nextTick queue, then goes into POLL stage, checks if anything queued there(nothing in this case)
2. Before moving to CHECK stage, it runs nextTick queue, print "next tick".
3. Moves to CHECK stage, run immediate queue, print "Immediate"
4. Loops back to TIMER stage, print "Timeout"

My confuse is **why setTimeout print out before Immediate?**

PS,

After I set Timeout delay from 0 to **3** or more, then the order is:

```
next tick
Immediate
Timeout
```

But this still does not explain why previous order JS event loop runs.

I wonder is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setImmediate` queues the function behind whatever I/O, event, callbacks that are already in the event queue. So, in this case `setTimeout` is already in queue.

**I think you should read https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ again. It has answer to all your questions. I am quoting following lines from above mentioned document**

**setImmediate() vs setTimeout()**

`setImmediate` and `setTimeout()` are similar, but behave in different ways depending on when they are called.

`setImmediate()` is designed to execute a script once the current poll phase completes.
`setTimeout()` schedules a script to be run after a minimum threshold in ms has elapsed.

The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called.

**Understanding `process.nextTick()`**

`process.nextTick()` is not technically part of the event loop. Instead, the `nextTickQueue` will be processed after the current operation completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop.

Looking back at our diagram, any time you call `process.nextTick()` in a given phase, all callbacks passed to `process.nextTick()` will be resolved before the event loop continues. This can create some bad situations because it allows you to "starve" your I/O by making recursive `process.nextTick()` calls, which prevents the event loop from reaching the poll phase.

Comment: Thanks, I am a lil confuse, could you point out which part of my understanding is incorrect( from step 1-4 ) based on that post u give? I also give setTImeout function delay as 1 or 2, but the result still same, until 3, the result changes

Comment: BTW, why setTimeout is I/O operation?

Comment: I meant I/O, events and callbacks and not I/O operation for ```setTimeout```. I modified the answer. About your earlier comment, I think it is better explained here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/. There are different phases in an event loop and timers are the first one which gets checked. It is not necessary that your 3-millisecond delay always works, it depends on the time it takes to the previous operation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I know where is wrong about my understanding, I thought POLL is the first phase to run, then loop back to TIMER phase.  **BUT, WHY "next tick" comes first before "Time out" since TIMER is the first phase to run and the time threshold is 0**? Or I think the question is **AFTER WHICH phase** does nextTick callback get ran?

Comment: Hi @Kuan, I modified answer. I think this node documentation https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick has the best explanation to all your questions.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figure it out myself. The problem is I did not differentiate the concepts between event queue and execute stack, the nextTick puts handler in current exe stack which is why it get called first. Thanks for the answer.